# R - questions with sample datasets for teaching

Tags: r

I am not sure whether this is a good question to ask here. We need to groom new hires in our company in such a way that pick up R in a good way. For this, we are required to build assignments, along with sample data, which can be given to new hires to clarify concepts. Do you know of sources where from we can procure assignments and data? The level of such assignments may vary from simple to tough. Please comment. Your answers are really needed.

Thanks

Comment: R has lots of sample datasets you can use. See `library(help=datasets)` for a list of included datasets

Comment: You should build assignments based on what they'll actually be doing at your company... probably written by people who have done it before.

Comment: start by hiring somebody who knows R, otherwise you won't have the *good way*.

Comment: Thank you everyone, for replying. Your suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Barranka, R provides a whole lot of data sets you could use for this purpose - and many packages deliver additional samples with them. Take a look at e.g. the machine learning benchmark package ([mlbench](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlbench/index.html)) or the [UCI machine learning repository](http://mlearn.ics.uci.edu/MLRepository.html), which were built for related purposes. A quick search on Google also brings up lists of dataset like [this one](https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/1001_datasets) or [this](https://blog.bigml.com/list-of-public-data-sources-fit-for-machine-learning/), which you might also want to investigate in more detail.

**Edit:** I strongly agree with what @Frank mentioned: you should design any test with the actual problems the employees will be solving in mind - because the focus of the demo/test/benchmark datasets you ask for is frankly quite broad.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your inputs. Your inputs are helpful.